# Django - What is the best way to set up a model with lots of similar fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to set up a questionnaire for users which would equate to nothing more than a big form with lots of radio choices. So my model is going to need spaces for a bunch of questions. My idea is to set it up so that I have a bunch of SmallIntegerFields with names like question1, question2, question3, etc. and then set up a dictionary for the verbose_names and choices and so forth. But this seems really inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you ever find yourself in a situation where you are adding more than one field of the same type to a database table, you need to normalize the database.  This involves setting up a separate table with entries for each question and then link them to whatever table you are trying to add multiple entries into.  More on database normalization here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

To implement in Django, use the following fields in your model depending on the type of link you need.

One to many:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Many to many: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand how normalization works here, although it seems like we're on the right track now. Could you give me an example?